# Using decodeURI with cookies javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

My problem at hand is that I need a variable that will keep track of all of my cookies so that I can split up the string in that variable into an array and then parse the string from there. I am wondering why the simple following code is not doing that for me?

```
var count = 0;          //keeps track of how many times this page has been visited
var lastVisit = new Date();     //records the last visit date in UTC format (or extra-challenge: in a user-friendly format like "Tuesday 10/12/2013 at 9:34:50")
var exDate  = new Date(lastVisit.getTime() + 30000);
var savedData = decodeURI(document.cookie);  //contains cookie contents

document.cookie = encodeURI("count=" + count.toString() + "; expires=" + exDate.toUTCString());
```

What I need to happen is whenever I set a cookie for it to be added to the savedData variable, I cannot figure out why this is not happening. Thank you

Comment: have a look at source code of jquery.cookie plugin. (I'm not saying use jQuery and cookie plugin, but maybe that would be an option for you).

Comment: `savedData` contains the value of `document.cookie` not a reference to it. So when `document.cookie` is altered, this will not affect the `savedData`.

Comment: To keep `savedData` in sync, you can create a helper function `setCookie` which sets the cookie, and updates the `savedData`.

Answer (score 12):

You're not supposed to encode 'expires='. It will turn into 'expires%3D', which is not what you want.
In addition to that, it might be a bad idea to use 'encodeURI', because it does not encode ';' and ',' as required.

You can use encodeURIComponent for encoding the cookie value, but it would be technically correct to use escape() to encode the cookie value.

So...

`document.cookie = "count=" + encodeURIComponent(count.toString()) + "; expires=" + exDate.toUTCString();`

...should do what you want.
The cookie consists of several parts; we're mostly interested in the name, the value and the  expiry date.

*(End of official answer)*

---

### Let's clear up the confusion on encoding cookies

If ever in doubt, contact the RFC, do not just pick anything you find on the Web that seems to work.

The cookie-name is of type *[token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-17)*, which means that only these values are allowed within it:
**0x21-0x27**, **0x2A-0x2B**, **0x2D-0x2E**, **0x30-0x39**, **0x41-0x5A**, **0x5E-0x7A** and **0x7E**.
In other words: The following values should be percent-encoded:
**0x00-0x20**, **'('**, **')'**, **','**, **'/'**, **':'**, **';'**, **'<'**, **'='**, **'>'**, **'?'**, **'@'**, **''**, **'['**, **']'**, **'{'**, **'}'** and **0x7F-0xFF**.

The cookie-value is of type *[cookie-octet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-9)*, which means that only these values are allowed within it:
**0x21, 0x23-0x2B, 0x2D-0x3A, 0x3C-0x5B, 0x5D-0x7E**.
In other words: The following values should be percent-encoded:
**0x00-0x20**, **0x22**, **','**, **';'**, **''** and **0x7F-0xFF**.

Now, the expiry date is encoded using toUTCString(), as you're correctly doing.
The result looks something like this: **Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT**
-So it will contain a comma. BUT! You're not supposed to encode anything, except the cookie-name and cookie-value strings.

*Note: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) says that escape() was deprecated in JavaScript 1.5, but it is technically incorrect to use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() for cookies. It is technically correct to use escape() for cookies.*

**[RFC 6265 section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4)** clearly states:

> NOTE: Despite its name, the cookie-string is actually a sequence of
> octets, not a sequence of characters.  To convert the cookie-string
> (or components thereof) into a sequence of characters (e.g., for
> presentation to the user), the user agent might wish to try using the
> UTF-8 character encoding [RFC3629] to decode the octet sequence.
> **This decoding might fail, however, because not every sequence of
> octets is valid UTF-8.**

As decodeURIComponent() is for unicode strings, and choke on byte values between 0x00 and 0xFF, they **can not** safely be used.
On the other hand, unescape() is **not** for strings, but for 8-bit byte-sequences, aka. **octets**, but only if your byte-sequences do not contain unicode characters.

If your cookie value contains unicode characters, you *should* however, use encodeURIComponent()/decodeURIComponent(), but you should also catch any exceptions, because the server may not send you exactly what you want to receive.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers also support `btoa` for encoding in Base64 and `atob` for decoding Base64.  All characters in Base64 are legal *cookie-octets* (when interpreted in ASCII or UTF-8).  So you can (at the cost of additional storage space) store a Base64 encoding of your persistent value as the cookie value, encoding (and decoding) as you persist  (and retrieve) the value.