# POST request failing to access cookie before sending

Tags: rest, cookies, fetch

I've got the following data being sent via a jQuery POST request:

```
let eventData = {
  user_id: getCookie('user_id'),
  // some other data...
};

$.post(someURL, eventData)
```

The user's unique id is being stored as a cookie and is fetched with this `getCookie()` method:

```
const getCookie = cname => {
  if (typeof document !== `undefined`) {
    let name = cname + '=';
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let allCookies = decodedCookie.split(';');
    let foundCookie = '';
    allCookies.forEach(cookie => {
      if (cookie.includes(name)) {
        foundCookie = cookie.split('=')[1];
      }
    });
    return foundCookie;
  }

  return '';
};
```

I have confirmed that the cookie is being stored correctly and that `getCookie()` works.

The strange thing is that somewhere around 2-5% of these requests are failing because the `user_id` being sent in the `eventData` is non-existent on the backend. I've spent hours troubleshooting and think that it might have something to do with `getCookie()` latency?

I make the POST request directly after formatting the data (and calling `getCookie()`). Is it possible that the cookie is not returned before the request is sent some of the time? It works at least 95% of the time so I'm very confused. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you accounted for the Cookie's `httponly` and `SiteSame` policies? Or issues with Origin (e.g. if the same page can be accessed from `https://yoursite.com` _and_ `https://www.yoursite.com`?)

Comment: @Dai I don't think it's a problem with cookie policies or origin because if the request fails and the user sends the same request half a second later, it works. It seems to be entirely random when it occurs and the cookie policy/origin would be the same in either case

Comment: I do see a few potential bugs in your code as-is: for example, `decodeURIComponent` is [not intended for use with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27281362/159145); `cookie.includes(name)` will return a false-positive if `name` is in the cookie's `value`; and your code doesn't stop after the first match. Those minor issues could all contribute towards unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Dai those are great points! I'm fairly confident that the last 2 bugs you described are not causing my issue. `name` is never the cookie value and even if the code doesn't stop after the first match, the cookie name should be unique. It is possible that `decodeURIComponent` is causing problems. I read the question you linked but it doesn't seem to suggest a robust alternative. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't really help further without being sat in front of your computer so I can inspect the raw HTTP messages and how the browser is interpreting it. In the meanwhile, all I can suggest is doing more logging. Also you should add a listener to `window.addEventListener('error', ... )` and log errors (e.g. in `localStorage` and POST them to your webserver when-possible).